Projection Morphism of Blowup
I'm currently reading the article A Short Course on Geometric Motivic Integration, by Manuel Blickle. In his proof of Theorem 3.3, the author considers the following.
Let $X'=\operatorname{Bl}_{0}\mathbb{A}^3_\mathbb{C}$, equipped with the usual projection $\pi:X'\longrightarrow\mathbb{A}^3_\mathbb{C}.$ Suppose $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^3$ has coordinates $x_0,x_1,x_2$. Note that
$$X'=\operatorname{Proj}\left(\frac{\mathbb{C}[x_0,x_1,x_2,z_0,z_1,z_2]}{I}\right),$$
where $I=(x_0z_1-x_1z_0,x_0z_2-x_2z_0,x_1z_2-x_2z_1)$.
In the proof, the author considers the affine patch of $X'$ given by $z_0=1$. It is claimed that $\pi$, restricted to this patch, corresponds to the canonical ring homomorphism
$$f:\mathbb{C}[x_0,x_0z_1,x_0z_2]\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}[x_0,z_1,x_2].$$
I'm having trouble seeing why $\pi$ corresponds to this form. When we consider the patch given by $z_0=1$, aren't we considering the open subscheme $D_+(z_0)$ of $X'$? If this is the case, shouldn't we have
$$D_+(z_0)=\operatorname{Spec}\left(\frac{\mathbb{C}[x_0,x_1,x_2,z_1/z_0,z_2/z_0]}{J}\right),$$
where $$J=\left(\frac{x_0z_1}{z_0}-x_1,\frac{x_0z_2}{z_0}-x_2,\frac{x_1z_2}{z_0}-\frac{x_2z_1}{z_0}\right)?$$
I'm not able to see how this construction leads to the aforementioned homomorphism $f$. Could someone let me know where I'm going wrong? Thank you for any help.

The idea is that we can use $J$ to eliminate variables. Write $Z_j = z_j/z_0$. First, note that the third generator is redundant since both monomials are equal to $x_0Z_1Z_2$ in the quotient. Taking the first two generators into account we get an isomorphism to $\mathbb{C}[x_0, x_0Z_1, x_0Z_2, Z_1, Z_2] = \mathbb{C}[x_0,Z_1, Z_2]$. Describing the morphism is then just a matter of tracking these identifications down.

(If you track it down, the map should send $x_0 \mapsto x_0$, $x_1 \mapsto x_0Z_1$, and $x_2 \mapsto x_0Z_2$)

@Daniel: Thank you! I just have one question. When you write $\mathbb{C}[x_0, x_0 Z_1, x_0 Z_2, Z_1, Z_2]=\mathbb{C}[x_0, Z_1, Z_2]$, how are you eliminating the terms $x_0 Z_1, x_0 Z_2$?

Let me elaborate on my comment, since writing polynomial rings like this can be a little sloppy. Let’s write $R$ for the coordinate ring of $D_+(z_0)$.
Since $x_1 - x_0Z_1 \in J$, for instance, we can replace the $x_1$ variable with $x_0Z_1$. That way you can remove that generator and describe the ring more simply.
More concretely, since $x_1 = x_0Z_1$ and $x_2 = x_0Z_2$ in $R$, we see it is generated as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra by $x_0, Z_1,$ and $Z_2$. As such there is a surjection $\mathbb{C}[x_1, Z_1, Z_2] \to R$. The kernel of this map is then $\mathbb{C}[x_1, Z_1, Z_2] \cap J = \{0\}$, where we view these as subsets of $\mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, x_3, Z_1, Z_2].$ Hence this is an isomorphism, as we needed,
